# How to write file to html with beauty?

Tags: html, node.js, js-beautify

I would like to  write to the test.html file this html:

```
<h2><strong><a href="http://awesome.com">AwesomeCom</a></strong><span>is awesome</span></h2>
```

Which will be lokk like:

```
<h2>
    <strong>
        <a href="http://awesome.com">
            AwesomeCom
        </a>
    </strong>
    <span>
         is awesome
   </span>
</h2>
```

so it is looks beauty and so on...and i tried this code:

```
var html = require("html");
var beautify_html = require('js-beautify').html;
var data = '<h2><strong><a href="http://awesome.com">AwesomeCom</a></strong><span>is awesome</span></h2>';
var beautyHtml= beautify_html(data);
fs.writeFile('test.html',beautyHtml, function (err) {});
```

But it is stays in one line...is it wrong what i wrote? or i have to add something? Thanks for the helps

Answer (score 2):

You're not doing anything wrong.  `js-beautify` definitely has bugs and limitations. It is likely you are encountering one of them.  You should file an issue.

That said, whether putting all elements on separate lines is correct is a bit more complex than it seems at first.  `js-beautify` is considerably more accurate than using a series of regular expressions or a tool that treats HTML the same as XML, but it is also does not fully parse the HTML before formatting it, so some behaviors that seem like they should be trivial are not implemented because the tool doesn't have enough information to do so safely.

**Example 1: HTML is not XML**

For example, if the input were XML, then the desired formatted output shown above would be fine.  But, because this is HTML, the desired output HTML shown in the question will display differently than the input.

Given this HTML (the sample input):

```
<h2><strong><a href="http://awesome.com">AwesomeCom</a></strong><span>is awesome</span></h2>
```

The displayed text will look like this:

```
AwesomeComis awesome
```

Given this HTML (the desired output):

```
<h2>
  <strong>
    <a href="http://awesome.com">AwesomeCom</a>
  </strong>
  <span>is awesome</span>
</h2>
```

The displayed text will look like this:

```
AwesomeCom is awesome
```

The formatted output HTML for the given input might be either of these:

```
<h2>
  <strong><a href="http://awesome.com">AwesomeCom</a></strong><span>is awesome</span>
</h2>

<h2><strong><a href="http://awesome.com">AwesomeCom</a></strong><span>is awesome</span></h2>
```

But it is definitely not the desired output HTML shown in the question, sorry.

**Example 2: Adding whitespace to HTML may change layout**

Next, let's consider why `<strong>` and `<a>` might not be safe to separate.  If the input were the following, then adding whitespace between `<strong>` and `<a>` would produce different displayed text:

```
<h2>The<strong><a href="http://awesome.com">AwesomeCom</a></strong><span>is awesome</span>!</h2>
```

In the case of the original input, adding a newline `<strong>` and `<a>` is safe, because there is no text between `<h2>` and `<strong>`, but `js-beautify` isn't smart enough to be sure of that. Even if it were, it is debatable whether that is the right behavior.  Doing that would produce the following behavior where formatting differs wildly depending on presence of leading text and/or whitespace:

```
<!-- Input --> 
<h2><strong><a href="http://awesome.com">AwesomeCom</a></strong><span>is awesome</span>!</h2>
<h2>The<strong><a href="http://awesome.com">AwesomeCom</a></strong><span>is awesome</span>!</h2>

<!-- Output --> 
<h2>
  <strong>
    <a href="http://awesome.com">AwesomeCom</a></strong><span>is awesome</span>!
</h2>
<h2>
  The<strong><a href="http://awesome.com">AwesomeCom</a></strong><span>is awesome</span>!
</h2>
```

**Example 3: Close to "real-world" input**

Finally, let's consider an input that is more like what was probably meant, with spaces in reasonable places:

```
<h2>The <strong><a href="http://awesome.com">AwesomeCom</a></strong> <span>is awesome</span>!</h2>
```

**Example 3-a: Multiple valid "beautified" HTML outputs**

There are a number of ways to reformat this. The `h2` tag ignores whitespace between it and it's contents and adding more whitespace where there is already whitespace is safe.  All of the below examples are reasonable depending on who you ask:

```
<h2>The <strong><a href="http://awesome.com">AwesomeCom</a></strong> <span>is awesome</span>!</h2>

<h2>
  The <strong><a href="http://awesome.com">AwesomeCom</a></strong>
  <span>is awesome</span>!
</h2>

<h2>
  The 
  <strong><a href="http://awesome.com">AwesomeCom</a></strong>
  <span>is awesome</span>!
</h2>
```

**Example 3b: Invalid "beautified" HTML output**

Some would even say that this next example is okay as well, but I'm not so sure.

```
<h2>
  The 
  <strong>
    <a href="http://awesome.com">AwesomeCom</a>
  </strong>
  <span>is awesome</span>!
</h2>
```

It adds a whitespace between between `<strong>` and `<a>` where there wasn't any before. Will the layout engine merge the space before and after `<strong>`?  What about if there's CSS that changes the font size for all `<strong>` tags? This might be safe in some cases, but would change the layout in just as many.

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to be isolated to `js-beautify`

There's a couple of related open issues on the github page:

- https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify/issues/1184
- https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify/issues/1167

You can also see this **not** working if you paste your arbitrary HTML into
http://jsbeautifier.org/

---

If I replace js-beautify for [pretty-data](https://github.com/vkiryukhin/pretty-data) I get the desired output, when formatting as XML:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var pd = require('pretty-data').pd;
var data = '<h2><strong><a href="http://awesome.com">AwesomeCom</a></strong><span>is awesome</span></h2>';
var pdHtml= pd.xml(data);

fs.writeFile('test.html',pdHtml, function (err){});
```

Results in

```
<h2>
  <strong>
    <a href="http://awesome.com">AwesomeCom</a>
  </strong>
  <span>is awesome</span>
</h2>
```

Comment: Sorry, but HTML cannot be treated like XML - space between elements has meaning in a number of cases depending on context.

Answer (score 0):

You could read from a file and then write it. It will keep the formatting and it's better practice than writing HTML in strings (unless you have to):

```
    fs.readFile(fs.realpathSync('input.html'), 'utf8', function (err, data){
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        fs.writeFile('output.html', data, function (err) {
            if (err) return console.log(err);
            console.log('File writing done');
        });
    });
```